# House inhabited by well-to-do Aztec descendents that is revealed to actually be a spaceship

Tags: story-identification

I must have read this paperback as a teenager, probably in the 1970s. I read it in German, but I'm pretty sure it was a translation. The cover may have featured a house, with the upper story detaching itself  from the rest, but I'm not sure.

It's set in the US, I only remember a love interest that leads a young man (possibly a detective) to inquire into the rich Mexicans(?) who are living in a house together.

One of the residents collects Aztec art, I think. The upshot is that the  upper floor of the house is in reality a spaceship with which they want to leave the Earth, taking the young man's love interest with them. The house featured also in the German title, but the rest is a blur.

The baddie is called something ending in "cotl" or "tetl".

Comment: Hey, welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange! This is a nice start. Are there any more details that you can add, such as where did you read it? What language was it in (and was it translated/original)? Do you remember anything about the cover, aside from it being it paperback? Who is the 'they' that want to leave Earth? (*Why* do they want to leave Earth?) If you could [edit] with any more details, that'd be great. See also [this FAQ on writing Story-ID questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/33591).

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, having to concentrate really hard on what I remember, I suddenly remembered the title. It was **A. E. van Vogt's *The House That Stood Still***.  Silly me, thank you!!!

[image: cover]

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_House_That_Stood_Still):

> Through various intrigues and investigations, a California estate lawyer learns that the pre-Toltec stone building upon which his retainer's ancestor, a conquistador, built a mansion four centuries earlier, confers immortality to those who know its secret. A cult of immortals operates secretly from the house and even has spaceships capable of travel to Mars where it has a base.

Comment: You can accept your own answer, 48 hours after asking the question.